# Does share operator works correctly?

Tags: rxjs6

Here is an example. The source is considered half cold half hot:

```
const subject = new Subject()

const source = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(concat(subject))

const hot = source.pipe(
    share()
)

setTimeout(() => {
    hot.subscribe(val => console.log(`a: ${val}`))

    subject.next(6)
}, 1000)

subject.next(4)
subject.next(5)
```

But the output:

```
a: 1
a: 2
a: 3
a: 6
```

Is this considered an expected result or a bug?

Comment: Here is my [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qilaza/8/edit?html,js,console,output) version

Comment: multicasting operators is one of the topics from my video course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The observable is cold in that it won't start producing anything until the first subscriber subscribes to it, and then it subscribes to the `Subject` and emits the values from the subject. The timeline is roughly this:

1. `subject` is created
2. `source` is created
3. `hot` is created
4. timeout is created
5. `subject` emits `4`
6. `subject` emits `5`
7. `hot` is subscribed to
8. `hot` emits `1`
9. `hot` emits `2`
10. `hot` emits `3`
11. `hot` subscribes to `subject`
12. `subject` emits `6`
13. `hot` emits `6`

Defining an observable only creates a **blueprint** of an observable, it's not actually **built** before you subscribe to the observable. This also means that a new observable is built (based on that blueprint) every time you subscribe to it.

`share` makes sure the observable is only built once, when the first subscribes subscribes to it. Any subsequent subscribers will receive the already built observable. It's *shared* between them.

Note that any signals emitted before a subscribes subscribes are not repeated. After being built, a shared observable is hot, so new subscribes will only receive events emitted after they subscribe.

**EDIT**:

Imagine you have an observable which calls a web api every 10 seconds:

```
let getFromWebApi = interval(10 * 1000).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => callWebApi())
)
```

Next imagine that you wanted to get these results in five different places in your code, you'd do this:

```
// Somewhere in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// Somewhere else in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A third place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A fourth place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A fifth place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);
```

Doing this in five different places would create five observables, each making a separate call to the web api every time 10 seconds has passed. Wouldn't it be better if you only made one call every 10 seconds and all the subscriptions shared the response? That's what share let's you do:

```
let getFromWebApi = interval(10 * 1000).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => callWebApi()),
  share()
)

// Somewhere in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);
// ^^^ This will create the observable and start making web requests
// every 10 seconds

// The ones below will not create new observables,
// but receive the same observable as above. They will all receive
// responses every 10 seconds when the original observable returns.

// Somewhere else in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A third place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A fourth place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);

// A fifth place in your code
getFromWebApi.subscribe(response => /* Handle response */);
```

If you have a look at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qidoyarihu/edit?js,console), you'll see that the subscribing to `source` five times, creates five "requests". Subscribing to `sharedSource` only creates one "request",

Comment: Only Cold Observable is considered a **blueprint**, the hot one isn't. So why the cold Observable is treated as cold (It is created when subscribe) but the hot one is treated as hot (it is created before it is subscribe) when both of them is turned to hot at the same time?

Comment: "`share` makes sure the observable is only built once". So it can be subscribe multiple of times. Should it relies on the first time it is subscribed or when it's built by `share`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I'll give it a try to answer: `share` won't become a hot observable until it's subscribed to for the first time. `share` is basically an alias for `publish().refCount()`. `concat` will not produce any values until the original observable (`of(1, 2, 3)`) is done. `concat` will then subscribe to `subject`. `var published = source.publish(); published.connect()` will make `published` a hot version of `source`

Comment: What i don't understand is what is the real meaning of making it hot and got first subscription because my ituitive intention was to get rid of the previous emitted values away?

Comment: `share` stay for some applicative reason and i want to know what is the real reason behind its implementation because just saying hot and cold is trivial

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more details on the `share` operator

Comment: Ok, thank you for your very dedicated answer. now i understand the problem. However, i have a final question. The real target of the `share` operator is to multicast the cold stream, not to make it cold or hot. Because the real effects of Subject and ReplaySubject are different, the capability of unicast and multi is only their side-effects, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in most cases it's related to the side effects. You could in theory be doing some heavy calculation without any side effect (calculate the `N` first numbers of the Fibonacci sequence, for instance) and to prevent repetition of the calculation you could share the observable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct result and here is why:

1. 'concat' will subscribe to Subject only after 'of(1,2,3)' is completed. But since you wrap hot.subscribe in setTimeout - subject.next(4) and 5 will not be re-emitted to hot subscription, since they run before hot is subscribed in SetTimeout function
2. of has sync emission by default with no delay, so you first get 1,2,3 from 'of' and then '6' from subject.next(6)
3. Using 'share' make sense if you have some delays between emissions and a few subscribers.

Comment: Why the cold is async (it is emitted when subscribe) but the hot is sync (it is emitted before subscribe) when both of them is turned into the sync version? Should it be synced at the time it's turned to hot. If it is correct, then the output is false!

Comment: If the observable is cold because it is created and emits values at the subscribe time. So is it considered hot when it only emits values at the subscribe time?!

Comment: share() works this way - once first subscriber is subscribed - it runs and share values as hot observable (for more  subscribers). Before first subscription it is not started.

Comment: share is an alias for  multicast(() => new Subject()) + refCount() (refCount starts sources observable with first subscription) So if no subscribers - then hot is not started.

Comment: use can put    hot.subscribe((v) => console.log('first subscriber value', v))    just before setTimeout to start hot sequence.

Comment: Ok i got the ideal, hot is multicast and cold in unicast. share is to make the cold multicast so it is considered make hot. But it's misconception for me because as i think, make hot is to evaluated all the previous values (and previous values often be misconception with cold values but it's not because the previous values can be either hot or cold)

Comment: Take a look at shareReplay(bufferSize).

Comment: This should be the real answer!